# how to extract specific paragraphs from a text file in R

Tags: regex, r, rstudio, text-processing

I'm using R studio to process a text file which has textual data in the following form:

```
*

A name
A date
A referene number

A text....bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla


*

A name
A date
A reference number

Another text....bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla

*
```

and same pattern over and over again.

I want to get the texts only and store each of them as an element in a list. I did A = grep("\*",myText) to get the number of lines where the * are. I want a loop through the file to get the text starting at A[1]+6 and ending at A[2]-1.

Comment: It would probably help us a little better if you didn't use **bla bla bla** and beginning/ending markers that are probably not in your actual data. I would recommend posting some of the actual data and also an attempt at what you have tried to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace "/tmp/out" with your filename

```
txt <- readLines("/tmp/out")
lns <- data.frame(beg=which(grepl("beginning of the paragraph i want",txt)),
                  end=which(grepl("end of the paragraph i want",txt)))
txt.2 <- lapply(seq_along(lns$beg),function(l){
                         paste(txt[seq(from=lns$beg[l],
                                       to=lns$end[l],
                                       by=1)],collapse=" ")
                                       })
txt.2

# or for referencing by the star, the lns is obtained this way
lns <- data.frame(beg=rev(rev(grep("[*]",txt) + 6)[-1]),
              end=(grep("[*]",txt) - 2)[-1])
```

Comment: I have a variable A which contains the line numbers of the *, the paragraphs I want to extract start at A[1]+6 because the paragraph starts after 6 lines from the * and end at A[2]-1. I think I need a loop her right?

Comment: right, if the star is the reference, you can calculate begins and ends line numbers from that reference